JQ Parsing a json stream input - Amazon Firehose
0
Hello,
I have a json stream coming into my aws firehose that can contain either metrics or report key-value pairs based on the data source. They look like this -
metrics stream

{ "metric": { "k1" : "v1", "k2" : "v2", ... } }

report stream

{ "report": { "k1" : "v1", "k2" : "v2", ... } }

I am trying to use JQ expressions to check if the json has("metric")/has("report") and then derive the values from the blob. or eg,
if has("metric") then "metric" else "report" end

This seemed valid syntax from the online JQ Playground(ref). However, it fails when it is defined as a Dynamic partitioning Key in the firehose. I want to read different keys from the json to define the output of the stream. For eg, both Keys - K1, K2 are important to be read and they are dependent on being able to parse if the parent key is metric/report.
In this stream, metirc/report form the 1st level partition key, followed by the K1 value. I am using below JQ syntax to derive K1,
if has("metric") then .metric.k1 else .report.k1 end

Error message -

JQ Subprocess failed due to: jq: error: syntax error, unexpected if
(Unix shell quoting issues?) at , line 2: {dataType:if
has("metric") then "metric" else "report" end} jq: 1 compile error
Error code: DynamicPartitioning.MetadataExtractionFailed

What's the mistake with JQ expression here. It seems pretty normal here but I am unable to get the right expression to verify the metric or report key.

Where does {dataType: come from? Note that if there's only a single key (metric or report, you could simply do .[].k1 to get the first value from the nested object.

I also need the parent key(report/metric) to derive final value. From the error message, dataType is referring to the parent key based on - if has("metric") then "metric" else "report" end

Is if has("metric") then "metric" else "report" end your full jq program? If it's part of a larger expression, you might need to put parentheses around it: {dataType:(if ... end)}
